# Wordpress - Using freewall.js showing up blank

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Trying to use [freewall](https://github.com/kombai/freewall) in a custom wordpress theme and I just keep getting a blank screen.

Was trying to use the flex-layout and used the code in my template:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var temp = "<div class='brick' style='width:{width}px;'><img src='/uploads/TFC/{index}.jpg' width='100%'></div>";
        var w = 1, h = 1, html = '', limitItem = 21;
        for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
            w = 1 + 3 * Math.random() << 0;
            html += temp.replace(/\{width\}/g, w*150).replace("{index}", i + 1);
        }
        $("#freewall").html(html);

        var wall = new Freewall("#freewall");
        wall.reset({
            selector: '.brick',
            animate: true,
            cellW: 150,
            cellH: 'auto',
            onResize: function() {
                wall.fitWidth();
            }
        });

        var images = wall.container.find('.brick');
        images.find('img').load(function() {
            wall.fitWidth();
        });

    </script>
```

URL is correct for the image and tested already. The JS is loaded in functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'freewall-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/freewall.js',  array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Also already in the headers.php:

```
    <?php wp_enqueue_script("freewall-js"); ?>
```

Still no clue why it's not working. i checked the console and the only clue I have is that this line has an error:

```
$("#freewall").html(html);
```

It says it's not a function. Any idea how I can fix?

Comment: Why 2 calls to wp_enqueue_script to enqueue freewall-js

Comment: you're right. turns out i didn't need the second one in headers.php. took it out but freewall still doesn't work though

Comment: Can you verify that freewall.js is being loaded correctly? Can you access freewall.js script from the url generated?
For eg. can you access this link:
http://www.YOU_SITE_URL.com/wp-content/themes/YOUR_CUSTOM_THEME_NAME/bootstrap/js/freewalss.js ?

Comment: Yes if I place the URL of the freewall.js in the browser it renders the js in plain text. It's also in the sources tab of chrome inspect.

Comment: Can you post the exact error that you get in the console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):405

Comment: You need to replace:
 $("#freewall").html(html);

with

jQuery("#freewall").html(html);

Comment: yeah still no go. No errors in the console though.

Comment: Put a few debug statements like console.log("Debug print 1"); at various places to know till which point does code execution go.

Also try changing the place where you are calling this code. Try moving it to footer or header or body to see if it effects anything

Comment: yeah had to give up on this had to send it out already. Used a plugin temporarily til I can get back to this and fix. Thanks for your patience though! Much appreciated!